# Does dateComponents use 24 hour time? (scheduling local notifications)

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponents, hour

This code would create a notification trigger that repeats every day at 10am, right?

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = 10
dateComponents.minute = 0
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
```

Would changing the 2nd line to `dateComponents.hour = 22` set it for 10pm?

Comment: Yes. 
What else would you expect to happen? Btw there is no need to set minute component to zero

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `DateComponents` uses 24 hours format by default.

If you want to know more about it, I would suggest [this](https://nshipster.com/datecomponents/) great article.

Comment: Note that hour component it is not limited to 24 hours. You can pass any amount of hours. try `DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2019, day: 1, hour: 40).date!` it will result in `"Jan 2, 2019 at 4:00 PM"`

Comment: @LeoDabus that is why I asked the question. I know you can set a one time notification 40 hours or 256 hours in the future, but for setting a repeating notification at an exact time (i.e. 10am every day or 10pm every day) I wasn't sure. I'm more used to using timeIntervalSinceNow, so typically I've used an integer to represent time added to the current time, not for setting the notification to an exact hour.